# Error while trying to install PythonMagic 0.9.11 on Fedora 21

Tags: python, g++, fedora, pythonmagick

The following is the output on the command line when I run `make` on the Pythin0.9.11 folder. I'm on fedora 21.

```
 [user@localhost PythonMagick-0.9.11]$ make          
 Making all in pythonmagick_src                
 make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/PythonMagick-0.9.11/pythonmagick_src'           
  CXX      libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo                      
 _DrawableFillRule.cpp:3:28: fatal error: boost/python.hpp: No such file or directory                       
  #include <boost/python.hpp>                           
                        ^             
 compilation terminated.                        
 Makefile:645: recipe for target 'libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo' failed         
 make[1]: *** [libpymagick_la-_DrawableFillRule.lo] Error 1          
 make[1]:  Leaving directory '/home/user/PythonMagick-0.9.11             /pythonmagick_src'                 
 Makefile:641: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed            
 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1         ``
```

The following is the trace from config.log

```
gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC) 
configure:3165: $? = 0
configure:3154: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3165: $? = 4
configure:3154: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3165: $? = 4
configure:3185: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3207: g++    conftest.cpp -lposix >&5
/bin/ld: cannot find -lposix
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3211: $? = 1
configure:3249: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "PythonMagick"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "PythonMagick"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.9.11"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "PythonMagick 0.9.11"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "PythonMagick"
| #define VERSION "0.9.11"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
```

I installed gcc-c++. Im not sure where am I going wrong or is there something I'm missing. I'm new to this.

Comment: use `-lboost_python` while linking?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` ?

Comment: ok thanks ... but where should i put the argument ?

Comment: look for `-lposix` in Makefile and add `-lboost_python` after that. You have another problem of `/bin/ld: cannot find -lposix`

Comment: ok that info really helped ... while checking for -lposix I observed that boost-devel was not installed ... hence all these missing dependencies ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those who had the same set of problem, well I understood the problem finally. I had installed boost but boost-devel was not installed.

`sudo yum install boost-devel`